# a simple graph has 7 vertices and 10 edges. each vertex has degree at most 3. Find the number of vertices of degree 2

Tags: graph-theory

I have created two equations based on this statement,
let x be the number of vertices with degree 1,
y be number of vertices with degree 2,
z be number of vertices with degree 3.

$x+2y+3z=20$ from the handshake theorem

and 
$x+y+z=7$

But am not sure where to proceed. Can anyone help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$
x+2y+3z = 20 \tag1
$$$$
x+y+z = 7 \tag2 .
$$
Multiplying $(2)$ by $3$ and subtracting $(1)$ from it we get
$$
2x + y = 1.
$$
Since $x,y$ are integers we conclude that $x=0$, $y=1$ and so $z = 6$.